# How to line break output after 20 loops?

Tags: c#, console-application

```
// Program displays every possible ID number for a company
// ID number is a letter, followed by a two-digit number
// For example -- A00 or Z99
// Go to a new display line after every 20 IDs
using static System.Console;
class DebugFive3
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char letter;
        int number;
        int row = 0;
        const int LOW = 0;
        const int HIGH = 99;
        const int NUMINROW = 20;
        for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; ++letter)
            for (number = LOW; number <= HIGH; ++number)
            {
                ++row;
                if (row > NUMINROW)
                {
                    row = 0;
                    WriteLine();
                }
              
                Write("{0}{1} ", letter, number);
                
            }
    }
}
```

Currently I need this program to display a new line after every 20 IDs. The code I have works for the first line, but each subsequent line gets to 21 IDs before a new line is formed. How can I get each line to 20 exactly? Keep in mind, this is a debugging exercise. So I don't want to drastically change the code.

```
// Program displays every possible ID number for a company
// ID number is a letter, followed by a two-digit number
// For example -- A00 or Z99
// Go to a new display line after every 20 IDs
using static System.Console;
class DebugFive3
{
   static void Main()
   {
      char letter;
      int number;
      const int LOW == 0;
      const int HIGH == 99;
      const int NUMINROW = 20;
      for(letter = 'A'; letter < 'Z'; ++letter)
        for(number = LOW; number > HIGH; ++number)
        {
           if(number % NUMINROW0)
              WriteLine();
           Write("{0}{{1} ", letter, number.ToString("D2"));
        }
   }
}
```

This is the original code for the exercise. I'd prefer not to delete all the variable and constants that are already declared. I added row to try and count the rows. But maybe there is another way.

Comment: "Keep in mind, this is a debugging exercise." What do you know already about debugging, in general? What is your explanation for why the code does what it does? Did you try to figure this out, for example, by using a debugger to monitor the value of `row` as the code runs? Did you try to reason out what the logical steps should be to solve the problem, for example, by drawing a flowchart and simulating the algorithm by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have to insert a new line **before** line `#20, #40, #60, ..., #20 * k, ...`
or put it in a bit different way we should enter a new line before each line

```
    #20 * k`, where `k > 0
```

We can do it with help of modulo aritrhmetics: if `number > 0` and `number % NUMINROW == 0` insert a new line
before printing current one:

```
    ... 
    const int NUMINROW = 20;

    for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; ++letter)
    {
        for (number = LOW; number <= HIGH; ++number)
        {
           if (number > 0 && number % NUMINROW == 0)
                WriteLine();

            Write($"{letter}{number:D2} ");
        }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the condition to `row >= NUMINROW` will make the new line be added when the row is exactly 20.

You could simplify the code by doing the following:

```
using static System.Console;

class DebugFive3
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; ++letter)
        {
            for (int number = 0; number < 100; ++number)
            {
                Write($"{letter}{number:D2} ");
                if (number % 20 == 19) WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you decide to use modulo, please provide a small explanation or link where OP can learn what modulo is.

Comment: Changing to >= works for every line except for the first. The first line now only has 19 but every following line has 20. So what can I do about the first line?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by combining the original code with corrections with fulvio's code.

```
// Program displays every possible ID number for a company
// ID number is a letter, followed by a two-digit number
// For example -- A00 or Z99
// Go to a new display line after every 20 IDs
using static System.Console;
class DebugFive3
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char letter;
        int number;
        const int LOW = 0;
        const int HIGH = 99;
        const int NUMINROW = 20;
        for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; ++letter)
        {
            for (number = LOW; number <= HIGH; ++number)
            {
                Write("{0}{1} ", letter, number.ToString("D2"));
                if (number % NUMINROW == 19)
                    WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More accurate is `number % NUMINROW == NUMINROW - 1` to avoid magic value `19`